# HTML: Browse folder and get local folder location

Tags: html

I have a live site and I want that if the user press the button Select Folder it will prompt user a dialog and search in his local directory what folder he wants. How can I possibly achieve this?

Similar to this but this is a file, I want a folder

```
   <form id="myForm" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="wp-content/themes/twentyelevenchild/generate.php?file_name=<?php echo $_GET['file_name']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="csv_file" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
    <input name="csv_file" type="file">
    <input type="button" class="btn btnGenerateCsv" value="Generate">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done in pure HTML/JavaScript for security reasons.

### EDIT

You should be looking to this for alternatives

http://www.swfupload.org

http://www.uploadify.org

Comment: i see , thanks ! i thought there is similar to file upload. :(